# Expression in interpolation

Tags: ruby

I have a case where, either `variable` is defined, or `variable` is `nil` and `alternative_variable` is defined. I need to implement logic into interpolation to choose the variable among these that is defined. When I do:

```
some_value: "#{ variable || alternative_variable }"
```

when `variable` is defined, everything works fine. The moment `variable` is not defined (and `alternative_variable` is present), I get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `variable' for #<#Class:0x007fc3c021bc28>:0x007fc3c006c030>
```

I've found a way to bypass the error by adding the following code block before interpolation:

```
<% variable ||= alternative_variable %>
```

But it feels dirty and not-rails-way. Is there a neat and tidy way to place logic inside interpolation directly?

Comment: Looks like you are confusing **undefined** variables and variables whose value is `nil`. They are completely different. Also, you should be careful with the word `present`. Especially in the context of Rails, it has a meaning different from what you intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with rails, it's just ruby. Try this:

```
some_value: "#{ defined?(variable) ? variable : alternative_variable }"
```

Comment: Oh and like yeah, it is ruby, but why double pipe operator was not working in this case?

Comment: Because that's how it works. It evaluates left side and if it's falsey, evaluates and returns right side. It can't evaluate left side, because the var is not defined.